# How is this simplified?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I have the following problem:

$$\frac{\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt x}{h}$$

Wolfram reduces it to:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{h+x}+\sqrt x}$$

[http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28x%2Bh%29^%281%2F2%29+-+x^%281%2F2%29%29+%2F+h](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28x%2bh%29%5E%281/2%29%20-%20x%5E%281/2%29%29%20/%20h)

But I can't think of how it comes to this conclusion. I'm really curious as to how this is solved. Any hints would be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Multiply both numerator and denominator by the conjugate of numerator.

Comment: Hint: use identity $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$.

Comment: By the way, this is how you must write it when programing if you want to avoid significant losses of accuracy.

Comment: Se http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/652245/convergence-proof-lim-x-rightarrow-infty-sqrt4xx2-sqrtx2x/652316#652316 for a generalization.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Multiply and divide by $\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}$

Answer (score 1):

Multiply both the numerator and denominator by the conjugate $\sqrt{x+h} + \sqrt x$:

$$\frac{\sqrt{x+h} - \sqrt x}{h}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{x+h} + \sqrt x}{\sqrt{x+h} + \sqrt x}\\
\frac{x+h+\sqrt{x+h}\sqrt x-\sqrt{x+h}\sqrt x-x}{h(\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt x)}\\
\frac{h}{h(\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt x)}=...$$