# Evaluating a limit with infinity

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm taking the limit as x approaches infinity from the left (-) of:

$$ \sqrt{x^2+2x}- \sqrt{x^2-2x} $$

However I'm not sure how to go about this. I'm at:

$$ \sqrt{ \frac{x^3+4x^2}{x+2x}}- \sqrt \frac{x^3-4x^2}{x-2x} $$

But I'm not sure if it's okay that I say:

"Well, $x^3$ grows exponentially faster than the other factors so the first line gives us $ \sqrt{ \infty} - \sqrt { - \infty } $ so undefined??

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/652245/convergence-proof-lim-x-rightarrow-infty-sqrt4xx2-sqrtx2x/652247#652247

Comment: Note that $(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}) = a+b$.

Comment: @Paze, what does x approaches infinity from the left (-) mean? That $\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiply numerator and denominator by $$\sqrt{x^2+2x}+ \sqrt{x^2-2x}$$
That is, multiply by $1$:
$$\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+2x}- \sqrt{x^2-2x}}{1}\cdot \dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+2x}+ \sqrt{x^2-2x}}{\sqrt{x^2+2x}+ \sqrt{x^2-2x}} = \dfrac{4x}{\sqrt{x^2+2x}+ \sqrt{x^2-2x}}$$

Now, divide numerator and denominator by $x = \sqrt{x^2}$, since $x \to \infty $ implies $x>0$.

ADDED: $$\dfrac{4x}{\sqrt{x^2+2x}+ \sqrt{x^2-2x}} = \dfrac {4x}{\sqrt{x^2\left(1 + \frac 2{x}\right)} + \sqrt{x^2\left(1 - \frac 2x\right)}} = \ldots$$

Comment: Hm, I end up with $ \frac{0}{stuff} $ is that a legitimate way of evaluating the limit to 0?

Comment: @amWhy, just a query why $x$ can not be negative?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, as $\;x\to\infty\;$ we can safely assume $\;x>0\;$ . BTW, +1

Comment: SOrry not 0, let me calculate further

Comment: Paze: No, be careful $(a + b)(a - b) = a^2 - b^2$ which in this case is $(x^2 + 2x) - (x^2 - 2x) = x^2 - x^2 + 2x - x^2 + 2x = 4x$.

Comment: @lab: READ my post..."since $x\rightarrow \infty$ implies $x>0."$

Comment: The last part of your solution confuses me. If I divide by $ \sqrt{x^2} $ what is supposed to happen?

Comment: See how I approached the problem in my "edit/added" portion. All you need now is to factor out $\sqrt{x^2} = x$, which then cancels with the factor of $x$ in the numerator, $$ \dfrac {4x}{x \left(\sqrt{1 + \frac 2x} + \sqrt {1 - \frac 2x}\right) }= \dfrac {4}{\sqrt{1 + \frac 2x} + \sqrt {1 - \frac 2x}}$$ after which you can now take the limit as $x\to \infty$.

Comment: Thank you, but the limit is approaching from the left, isn't that worth mentioning?

Comment: No, because $x$ can only approach $\infty$ from the left! That is, approaching infinity means growing without bound, and to "grow" means moving from "left" to "right".

Comment: @amWhy, could it be that Paze thinks $\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}$?

Comment: Because the limit is not the same in $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, $x$

HINT:
Setting $\displaystyle\frac1x=h,$

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}[\sqrt{x^2+2x}-\sqrt{x^2-2x}]=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sqrt{1+2h}-\sqrt{1-2h}}{|h|}$$

Now, $$\sqrt{1+2h}-\sqrt{1-2h}=\frac{1+2h-(1-2h)}{\sqrt{1+2h}+\sqrt{1-2h}}=\frac{4h}{\sqrt{1+2h}+\sqrt{1-2h}}$$

as $\displaystyle h\to0\implies h\ne0\implies\lim_{h\to0}\frac  hh=1$